# Access multiple items with not equal to, !=

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas DataFrame object `df`. It is a train schedule listing the date of departure, scheduled time of departure, and train company.

```
import pandas as pd
df = 

            Year  Month DayofMonth  DayOfWeek  DepartureTime Train    Origin
Datetime
1988-01-01  1988    1     1         5        1457      BritishRail   Leeds
1988-01-02  1988    1     2         6        1458      DeutscheBahn  Berlin
1988-01-03  1988    1     3         7        1459      SNCF           Lyons
1988-01-02  1988    1     2         6        1501      BritishRail   Ipswich
1988-01-02  1988    1     2         6        1503      NMBS          Brussels
....
```

Now, let's say I wanted to select all items "DeutscheBahn" in the column "Train".

I would use

```
DB = df[df['Train'] == 'DeutscheBahn']
```

Now, how can I select all trains except DeutscheBahn and British Rails and SNCF. How can I simultaneously choose the items *not* these?

```
notDB = df[df['Train'] != 'DeutscheBahn']
```

and

```
notSNCF = df[df['Train'] != 'SNCF']
```

but I am not sure how to combine these into one command.

```
df[df['Train'] != 'DeutscheBahn', 'SNCF']
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
df[~df['Train'].isin(['DeutscheBahn', 'SNCF'])]
```

`isin` returns the values in `df['Train']` that are in the given list, and the `~` at the beginning is essentially a `not` operator.

Another working but longer syntax would be:

```
df[(df['Train'] != 'DeutscheBahn') & (df['Train'] != 'SNCF')]
```

Answer (score 10):

I like using the query method as it's a bit more clear

```
df = df.query("Train not in ['DeutscheBahn', 'British Rails', 'SNCF']")
```