# How to drop rows from a pandas dataframe by a column condition with a string - keep getting error "truth value is ambiguous"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that includes data from different age groups - and I want to remove all children (or keep all adults). So, I want to drop all rows which satisfy the condition:

`df.age_category != "newborn" & != "child" & != "schoolage"`

I know this question has been asked a couple of times and I have tried so many of the approaches on here (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397982/pandas-dataframe-access-multiple-items-with-not-equal-to/34398006), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679930/how-to-drop-rows-from-pandas-data-frame-that-contains-a-particular-string-in-a-p/43399866), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)).

Each time I get the following error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

This happens even when I only use one condition, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with the `or` / `and` statements. It also doesn't matter whether I assign the condition to a variable and then use that or if I use a loop with if statements. And it happens whether I want to get rid of children or keep the adults in the dataset, so it's not a problem with the `df.drop()` function, either.

Comment: Use, [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) ```df[~df.age_category.isin(["newborn", "child", "schoolage"])]```

Comment: That finally worked, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
df.age_category != "newborn" & != "child" & != "schoolage"
```

to

```
all(df.age_category != "newborn",df.age_category != "child",df.age_category != "schoolage")
```